# How do I expose ports in Docker on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I have a properly installed copy of Docker CE on my Windows 10 Pro machine.

I am trying to run a simple node app using `docker-compose` and be able to dynamically update the code while running in docker. I followed [this website](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) to build it out, and my code can be found [here](https://github.com/alyons/diet-program).

When I navigate to `localhost:8080` while running the code locally, I get my web page. When I run it through Docker, I get "This page isn't working" from my web browser (same url). I have made sure to stop running locally before running in Docker so that the ports aren't crossed.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.10.2

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app

ENV HOME=/home/app

COPY package.json npm-shrinkwrap.json $HOME/diet-program/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/diet-program
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  diet-program:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/diet-program
      - /home/app/diet-program/node_modules
```

The dev command is mapped to: `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot`

Comment: You need to add `VOLUME /home/app/diet-program` to the Dockerfile. This creates the mount point docker compose will user to mount your application source directory.

Comment: Btw, what's your actual question? Your port settings look fine. What are you seeing that's making you think it's not working?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: I cannot see my webpage when I run it using Docker, but I can see it when I run locally. The docker-compose build seems to be working correctly as does docker-compose up.

Answer (score 0):

For expose ports try to change line

```
ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

into

```
ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

in `docker-compose.yml` file

More details about expose ports here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

For check if you call a correct IP check with command `docker inspect <container_name>` in "NetworkSettings" and look at IPAddress.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax check, I updated my code to have quotes and still nothing.

Comment: You call from correct IP? Try command `docker inspect <container_name>` and check "NetworkSettings" for port mapped and for IP look at IPAddress.

Comment: I am just running it locally, is there something special I need to do to hit the docker instance?

Comment: Run `docker-machine ip <machine_name>` and try hitting that.